# spark-with-hadoop connect minio got Forbidden error

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, minio

I tried to connect MinIO using spark(packed with hadoop), Then I got this error:

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: s3a://hudi/env.txt: getFileStatus on s3a://hudi/env.txt: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: 1778F9AB820DCD94; S3 Extended Request ID: dd9025bab4ad464b049177c95eb6ebf374d3b3fd1af9251148b658df7ac2e3e8; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: dd9025bab4ad464b049177c95eb6ebf374d3b3fd1af9251148b658df7ac2e3e8:403 Forbidden
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:249)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:170)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.s3GetFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:3286)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.innerGetFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:3185)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:3053)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.getFileStatus(Globber.java:115)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.doGlob(Globber.java:349)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:202)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.globStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:4253)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:276)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:244)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:332)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:205)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:300)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:296)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:300)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:296)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2289)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1030)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1029)
  ... 47 elided
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: 1778F9AB820DCD94; S3 Extended Request ID: dd9025bab4ad464b049177c95eb6ebf374d3b3fd1af9251148b658df7ac2e3e8; Proxy: null)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1828)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1412)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1374)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5227)
  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5173)
  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1360)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.lambda$getObjectMetadata$6(S3AFileSystem.java:2066)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retryUntranslated(Invoker.java:412)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retryUntranslated(Invoker.java:375)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getObjectMetadata(S3AFileSystem.java:2056)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getObjectMetadata(S3AFileSystem.java:2032)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.s3GetFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:3273)
  ... 70 more
```

The spark version I got is **"spark-3.2.4-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz"**.

I also added **"aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.901.jar"** **"hadoop-aws-3.3.1.jar"** in my spark jars dir.

Then I started spark shell with this code:

```
./spark-shell \
--conf 'spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer' \
--conf 'spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem' \
--conf 'spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint=http://127.0.0.1:9000' \
--conf 'spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key=minioadmin' \
--conf 'spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key=minioadmin'\
--conf 'spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access=true' \
--conf 'spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled=true' \
--conf 'spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.signing-algorithm=S3SignerType'
```

Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

- There is a whole "troubleshooting s3a" document in the Hadoop s3a connector: [please read and trust more than ageing stack overflow posts](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.html)
- You don't have read permissions. usually this means lack of authentication, password etc. Review
- your error includes an extended request ID. That's normal for AWS S3, but not generally from any third party store. *Have you actually set `fs.s3a.endpoint` to refer to your minio server, or does it still point at AWS S3?*
- finally, you state you have a spark distribution with the hadoop-3.2 JARs *and added a hadoop-aws-3.3.1 JAR to it*. that is never going to work, you have to be in sync with hadoop-* jars, just as you must with spark JARs. this is a foundational issue.